# D3 Angular chart axis labels

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/MErMvIgG9MOdXmjBPZVq?p=preview

Final piece of this D3 puzzle I think.

How do I add lables to the axis.

I thought this would add lables to the axis.

```
private drawAxis() {
    this.g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(this.x))
        .classed('x axis', true)
        .call(this.x)
        .append('text')
        .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + (this.width/2) + " ," +
            (this.height + this.margin.top + 20) + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Letters");
    this.g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(this.y).ticks(10, "%"))
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "axis-title")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", "0.71em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Frequency");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your x-axis label isn't showing because your transform rule is pushing it down too far. It's already inside the group that has a transform of `translate(0, this.height)`, so it only needs to be pushed down an additional 25 pixels or so.

You might need to define a fill for your text elements, either by adding a line to your code saying `style('fill','black')` or in your stylesheet `.axis-title { fill: black }` (don't forget to add the class of `axis-title` to your x axis label as well).